# Why this htaccess redirect doesn't work?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Although many redirects work fine on my Wordpress site, there are many others that don't work like this:

RewriteRule ^%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D9%83%D9%8A%D9%83-%D9%81%D8%B7%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A7/$ http://www.allabout-cook.com/%D9%81%D8%B7%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A7/ [R=301,L]

So, what's the problem?

Comment: What are your source and target URLs?

Comment: This is the source:
http://www.allabout-cook.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D9%83%D9%8A%D9%83-%D9%81%D8%B7%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A7/

And this is the target:
http://www.allabout-cook.com/%D9%81%D8%B7%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A7/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule as your top redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^الكراب-كيك-فطائر-الكابوريا/?$ http://www.allabout-cook.com/فطائر-الكابوريا/ [L,B,NE,R=301]
```

It is important to keep both `B` and `NE` flags in this rule.

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

Comment: Fine, it works. 
But can I use the percent encoded URL? because it's hard to me to decode a lot of URLs.

Comment: You can but it will be very long rule. You have to replace each `%` by `\x` for that